# Trying to print out an html table in Netbeans

Tags: java, html, mysql, servlets, netbeans

I'm learning to use java and netbeans to talk to an databse. 
I have a database called tunafishes with several bits on info. I want to print an html table using netbeans. I thought I'd set everything up, but when I try to print the table nothing comes out. Not sure what i'm missing or If I'm in the wrong file...

Code from TunaServlet

```
package ViewLayer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import businesslayer.TunasBusinessLogic;
import transferobjects.Tuna;
import java.util.List;

/**
*
* @author Samuel
*/
public class TunaServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Sam Murdock</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Sam Murdock</h1>");
        out.println("date:" + java.time.LocalDate.now().toString());
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("time:"+java.time.LocalTime.now().toString());
        out.println("<br>");
        TunasBusinessLogic logic = new TunasBusinessLogic();
        List<Tuna>tunas=logic.getAllTunas();
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>Tuna Id</td>");
            out.println("<td>Genus Name</td> ");
            out.println("<td>Species Name</td>");
            out.println("<td>Common Name</td>");
            out.println("<td>Max Weight</td>");
            out.println("<td>IUCN Status</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        for(Tuna tuna: tunas){
            out.printf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%f</td><td>%s</td></tr>",
                    tuna.getTunaId(), tuna.getGenusName(),tuna.getSpeciesName(), tuna.getCommonName(), tuna.getMaxWeight(), tuna.getIucnStatus());
            out.println("</table>");
        }out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

If i'm missing a file you need to see let me know and I'll copy it too. It prints my name and the time and date no problem but then doesn't print anything for the table.

Answer (score 0):

you are closing the table inside the for loop, move it outside for loop

```
.... 
List<Tuna>tunas=logic.getAllTunas();
out.println("<table>");
out.println("<tr>");
  out.println("<td>Tuna Id</td>");
  out.println("<td>Genus Name</td> ");
  out.println("<td>Species Name</td>");
  out.println("<td>Common Name</td>");
  out.println("<td>Max Weight</td>");
  out.println("<td>IUCN Status</td>");
out.println("</tr>");
for(Tuna tuna: tunas){
     out.printf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%f</td><td>%s</td></tr>",tuna.getTunaId(), tuna.getGenusName(),tuna.getSpeciesName(), tuna.getCommonName(), tuna.getMaxWeight(), tuna.getIucnStatus());
    }
    //* move table closing tag out of for loop
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}
```

Comment: I tried moving the table close but it didn't fix anything. Thank you for the heads up about the wrong place to close it.